# Codeigniter controller not found getting 404

Tags: codeigniter, controller

Hello I created a simple controller called about.php and when I go to the url: domain/index.php/about
or domain/about I get a 404 error.
I have a controller called test.php and it works. it echos out Hello World. If I copy test.php to a new file name the new file does not work either. I am so very confused.

-J

Comment: Please post the `about` controller code and any custom routes you may have added to `routes.php`.

Comment: Does `domain/index.php/test` work?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this one:

```
<?php 
class About extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
  echo "Hello World";
}
}
```

that means create index action in about controller.